# Thymeleaf attribute and modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Edited:
Just figured out that i need JS. Plase, help me with this. I have a `th:attr="data-object-id=${department.id}"` who store Department id, which i need to put in the modal in the `<input id="ids" name="ids" type="text" class="validate">`.

How will JS or JQuery looks like? I am trying to write, but all time null or undefined.

```
<tr th:each="department : ${departments}">
        <td class="dep_id" th:text="${department.id}">1</td>
        <td th:text="${department.name}"></td>
        <td>
            <div class="dep_edit">
                <a class="settings_dep" th:href="@{'/departments/' + ${department.id} + '/'}"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a>
                <a class="edit_dep modal-trigger" href="#modal3" th:attr="data-object-id=${department.id}"><i
                        class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                <form method="post" th:action="@{'/departments/' + ${department.id} + '/delete'}" class="inline">
                    <button type="submit" value="" class="link-button delete_dep">
                        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>


<div id="modal3" class="modal modal-departments">
        <div class="modal-dep modal-content">
            <h4>Update Department</h4>
            <a href="#" class="dep-modal-close modal-close"><i
                    class="material-icons icon_close">close</i></a>
            <p>Update Department name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dep-modal">
            <form id="dep-update" class="col s12" th:action="@{'/departments/update'}" method="POST">
                <div class="row-modal-dep">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="depName" name="name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <input id="ids" name="ids" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="name">Department Name</label>
                        <i class="edit-dep-marker material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="modal-close waves-green green btn-dep btn" type="submit" form="dep-update">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to give ID value of department to MODAL, so i can update it

[image]

My Departments class is easy. Only ID and name;

Comment: Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: Edited question and added picture

Comment: Let's show your class `Department` or your Java code (not only view layer code)

Comment: It is a simple class with fields: id, name;

Comment: A quick trick to achieve that is to create a hidden html-element on your html page and then get the value of that html-element using its id on the modal.

Comment: @Sumit i tried this, but it is not working like i wanted. I created data- which in html show ID as expected. For every field own id. But when i try to parse it in modal it is return only first id which found. This not my goal

Comment: @Neewbie treid like this to get the id of every element  :-
**th:onclick="'javascript:showFunctionModal(\'' + ${department.id} +'\');'">** and then your function would be like this . **function showFunctionModal(id){ // hide and show modal logic }**

Comment: Implement this function on your html element whose id you want to fetch.

Comment: @Sumit This function gives correct id, of each row, thanks, but now the main problem. How this id will pass to modal? As you can see on the pic, i have href to #modal3 on every row. When i try to use function with e.relatedTarget, target, currentTarget it is only work for first row. Another one not work. Should i change my html somehow or script?

Comment: NOW i solved problem. Thank you so much @Sumit. You awesome!!!!

Comment: Great.!! Let me post it as an answer so that it'd help someone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 tricks to achieve the same (PS - I'm not a Frontend expert):-

1.)  Is to create a hidden html-element on your html page & set the value and then get the value of that element using jquery on your modal.

2.) create a function on that html-element and pass the dynamic value to it and then implement your modal hide/show code inside that function, something like this :- -

```
<a class="edit_dep modal-trigger" th:onclick="'javascript:showFunctionModal(\'' + ${department.id} +'\');'"><i
                        class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
```

and your function would be something like this :-

```
function showFunctionModal(id) {
        //logic to hide & show function
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `show.bs.modal` event and capture the department id as shown below:

```
$('#modal3').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
   var target = e.relatedTarget;
   var departmentId = $(target).data('object-id');
   $("#ids").val(departmentId);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Mohamed, but it is for Bootstrap. I have materialize and your script do not want work

Comment: Tried your suggest to attach click to the id of my a, but this give me another bug `$('#dep-modal-pic").click(...)` It is give only value of first row. Another just not work

Comment: No I didnt suggest to attach on click. That was for a different post and I also mentioned in that post that the better answer is posted here.

Comment: @Neewbie Can u show your code where you have incorporated the modal lifecycle event handler? Using the modal lifecycle is much more cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Huge thanks @Sumit.

`th:onclick="'javascript:showFunctionModal(\'' + ${department.id} +'\');'">` on the field which id i want to fetch and then in ready modal function set id.

```
function showFunctionModal(id) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.modal3').modal();
            $("#ids").val(id);
        });
```