# JavaScript script to inset data from page to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I know, that this question was asked many many times, but i try and code not working.

This function must parse data from my 
`<a id="dep-modal-pic" class="edit_dep modal-trigger" href="#modal3" th:attr="data-dep_id=${department.id}">` and put dep_id to modal input.
var bookId not working. when i give fixed value to this var it is work, but in my thymeleaf template every new field is new value because

```
<tr th:each="department : ${departments}">
            <td class="dep_id" th:text="${department.id}">1</td>
            <td th:text="${department.name}"></td>
</tr>
```

So, please, can you correct my code? I cant sleep, all day making this thing and still not working.

I need value `dep_id` to modal input

```
<input id="ids" name="ids" value="" type="text" class="validate">


$('#modal3').click(function(e) {
      var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('dep_id'); 
      $(e.currentTarget).find('input[id="ids"]').val(bookId);
    });
```

Comment: A quick trick to achieve that is to create a hidden html-element on your html page and then get the value of that html-element using its id on the modal.

Answer (score 0):

The click handler should be attached to `#dep-modal-pic`, something like:

```
$('#dep-modal-pic").click(...)
```

Update:
This is a duplicate of [Thymeleaf attribute and modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562444/thymeleaf-attribute-and-modal)
Please check my answer on the other post which is more clear