# Problem in managing a modal to make a use case , I cant delete the selected item but only the first

Tags: html, spring, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, thymeleaf

I have a collection of objects, each identified by a different ID. These objects are shown in a table and for each of these objects it is proposed the possibility to carry out an operation from the controller using the unique id. Unfortunately if I want to do this through the use of Modal. It is carried out (in this case the elimination) always for the first object of the collection.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-light" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">DATA PROGRAMMATA</th>
                    <th scope="col">MOTIVO DELLA VISITA</th>
                    <th scope="col">STATO PRENOTAZIONE</th>
                    <th scope="col">GIORNI ALLA SCADENZA</th>
                    <th scope="col">ESITO</th>
                    <th scope="col">NOTA</th>
                    <th scope="col">NUMERO RINVII</th>
                    <th scope="col">DATA EFFETTIVA</th>
                    <th scope="col">FUNZIONI</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody
                th:each="convocazione : ${dipendente.getConvocazioniOrdinatePerData()}">
                <tr align="center">
...
    <td>
                            <!-- Button trigger modal 0 Cancellazione -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#exampleModalCenter0">Cancella convocazione</button>
                            <!-- Modal Cancellazione numerato 0-->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter0" tabindex="-1"
                                role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle0"
                                aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle0">Attenzione!
                                                Richiesta di cancellazione</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">Questa modifica puo'
                                            compromettere la stabilita' del sistema qualora la correttezza
                                            dei dati fosse sbagliata , assicurati di aver inserito tutti i
                                            dati correttamente prima di procedere.</div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <a th:href="@{'/rimuoviConvocazione/' + ${convocazione.id}}"
                                                class="btn btn-danger" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Cancella
                                                convocazione</a>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- Fine Modal Cancellazione numerato 0-->
                        </td>
...
```

This is the controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rimuoviConvocazione/{id}")
    public String rimuoviConvocazione(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
        Convocazione convocazione = convocazioneRepository.getOne(id);
        rigaDiConvocazioneRepository.deleteAll(convocazione.getRigheDiConvocazioni());
        if(!convocazione.getRinvii().isEmpty())
            for(Rinvio r : convocazione.getRinvii())
                rinvioRepository.deleteById(r.getId());
        convocazioneRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "redirect:/dipendenti/dettaglioDipendente/"+convocazione.getDipendente().getId();
    }
```

Comment: Similar question is being answered, check this out, this query is may-be similar to yours - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562444/thymeleaf-attribute-and-modal/54570781#54570781

Comment: I already saw that post, I could not solve it. I'm not practical in the front end, I'm waiting for your solution

Comment: @LucaDeAngelis Could you please post your **controller** code. How can we suppose to figure out the problem without seeing your controller code.

Comment: @Ahmet i have added the controller code . the code works if I do not use the modal but a simple button link. I think it's a problem of passing the id code to the modal

Comment: @LucaDeAngelis if that is the case then you most probably be passing the first ID to the modal.  Did you checked the generated Delete link with Google Dev Tools or something.

Comment: @Ahmet Not using the modal deletes the correct object on which I press the function button. I don't understand why it always eliminates the first element when I use the modal

Comment: You should be checking the `<a href>` value when you use modal (you should be using Chrome Dev Tools or similar). You will see that your link is wrong.

Comment: Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: No one solution?

Comment: I have tried to create a variable with id but nothing